# Debug a module built with Boost.Python in QtCreator

Tags: c++, python, debugging, qt-creator, boost-python

I have a module built with Boost.Python and I want to debug it in QtCreator (or perhaps gdb). I prefer a visual environment if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://leohart.wordpress.com/2010/10/18/debug-a-module-built-with-boost-python-within-qtcreator/

After a while, I finally figured out how to do it. I documented it in the link above so future searches can find it.